# coma and double quotes in the field in SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

how to handle coma and double quotes in the field in SSIS?

when I load this I am getting data in separate columns:

Address

> sec-34,Menara lane,"NJ"

can anyone give a solution in this?

Comment: I guess the delimiter defined is comma? The best thing to do is not use comma as a delimiter (this is one of the worst delimiters and should be banned). A better delimiter is tab. Do you have any control over how this file is generated?